# ASP.NET MVC Session.IsNewSession issue with Google Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firefox, google-chrome, session-timeout

I'm currently working on a Session expired piece of logic for my ASP.NET 3.5 MVC 2 project to log out a user and redirect them to the AccountController LogOn action.

I have the following attribute on all my actions that care about session state, and this piece of code works in IE 8, but not Firefox 4 or Google Chrome 10. The symptom is when I attempt to navigate to a view represented by an action with my [SessionExpireFilter] attribute, the ctx.Session.IsNewSession property in the below code is evaluating as "true" every time, even if I'm only seconds into my 30-minute session.

```
public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // check if session is supported 
        if (ctx.Session != null && ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must 
            // have timed out 
            string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
            if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                ctx.Response.Redirect("~/Account/LogOn");
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to figure out why Chrome and Firefox are behaving this way, but IE is not? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is not working in FF as I originally believed. I am being directed to my LogOn action immediately after logging in and attempting to access an action with my SessionExpireFilter attribute.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ASP.NET will create a new session for every request unless you store something in it.
Try adding the code below to your `Global.asax`. It works in my MVC2 and MVC3 apps with the same `SessionExpireFilterAttribute`.

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
    Session["Dummy"] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Fascinating. So the fact that IE doesn't request a new session is the actual unusual behavior here?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the browser, it's the behavior of ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

We can add session_start method in **Golbal.asax** file in MVC appliaction.

```
  protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {                    
       HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("UserId" , null);
      }
```

Then when application starting your session will be created. and then session will be not **isNewSession** **'True'**, otherwise it will be always **'True'**