# How do I prevent a redirect loop when using SessionExpireFilterAttribute to catch session timeouts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session-timeout

Again, I'm new to MVC, so please go easy on me.  I need to redirect a user to the login page when the session expires.  I found a way to do this by overloading the SessionExpireFilterAttribute class, but my site gets caught in a redirect loop.  I don't know enough about MVC to figure out what is going on.  Can someone explain how to prevent the redirect loop?

The main page I'm using as a template is http://www.codeblockdrive.com/2012/12/mvc-custom-filters-session-timeout.html, but I've also searched stackoverflow and looked at several pages including 
[MVC Session timeout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800657/mvc-session-timeout-issue), 
[ASP.NET MVC Session.IsNewSession issue with Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435124/asp-net-mvc-session-isnewsession-issue-with-google-chrome/5435349#5435349), 
[Redirecting to specified controller and action in asp.net mvc action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490401/redirecting-to-specified-controller-and-action-in-asp-net-mvc-action-filter/1503981#1503981).

This page [Error: "This webpage has a redirect loop" in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037395/error-this-webpage-has-a-redirect-loop-in-asp-net-mvc) seems to be the closest to my problem, but I tried the solution mentioned there (moving the SessionExpireFilter to a separate controller), but it didn't help me.

Here is the code to catch a session timeout.  It is in a file called FilterConfig.cs in the folder App_Start:

```
 public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new SessionExpireFilterAttribute());
    }
}

public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // check if session is supported
        if (ctx.Session != null)
        {
            // check if a new session id was generated
            if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
                // have timed out
                string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0 && sessionCookie != "reset"))
                {
                    ctx.Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Login");
                }
            }
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

I then have this code in a controller called ErrorController.cs.  I also tried this in AdminController.cs, but I moved it to a separate controller than the Login method.

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [SessionExpireFilter]
    public ActionResult Index2()
    {
        // This method will not execute if our session has expired

        // render Home Page
        return View();
    }
}
```

Then here is the login method.  It is in AdminController.cs.  When it gets to the "return view" portion, it goes to SessionExpireFilterAttribute.

```
public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (Session["AdminUserName"] != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ModelAdminLogin obj_MAL = new ModelAdminLogin();

        Session["Captcha"] = ClientUtility.GenerateRandomCode();

        Session["ErrMsg"] = null;

        if ((Request.Cookies["ADMINUSERNAME"] != null) && (Request.Cookies["ADMINPASSWORD"] != null))
        {
            obj_MAL.UserName = ClientUtility.DecryptString(Request.Cookies["ADMINUSERNAME"].Value);
            obj_MAL.Password = ClientUtility.DecryptString(Request.Cookies["ADMINPASSWORD"].Value);
            obj_MAL.RememberMe = true;

            return View(obj_MAL);
        }
        else
        {
            return View(obj_MAL);
        }
    }
```

So to summarize, when a session times out, the site calls SessionExpireFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuting (as desired) which redirects to the view Admin/Login (as desired), but before the page appears to the user, it calls SessionExpireFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuting which starts the loop over again.  Eventually, I get the error message "This webpage has a redirect loop."  I need a way to redirect to the login page when a session ends and not have it go back to the SessionExpireFilterAttribute class once it hits the login page.

I'd be appreciative for any help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are putting attribute on login action as well , that is causing loop. Use `AllowAnonymous` attribute on login action:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public ActionResult Login()
{

}
```

Comment: That did not work.  I added [AllowAnonymous] before the Login method, but it got caught in the same redirect loop.  There wasn't an attribute for that method before.  Thanks for the suggestion; let me know if you have anything else I could try.

Comment: @boilers222 can you show your action of login how you write and better if show complete controller

Comment: The login portion of the controller is shown in my original question.  That's exactly how it looks in the controller (no attributes or filters).

Comment: Then you have to put check in filter that if request coming from login action render login view

Comment: Thanks Ehsan.  How would I do that?  Again, it's my first project in MVC and I inherited a partially done site, so I'm learning as I go.

Comment: @boilers222 I once blogged article on it see : http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2014/08/aspnet-mvc-check-user-is-logged-in-and.html  this may help out

Comment: Ehsan...thanks for the help.  I didn't follow everything on your blog, but I was able to get something to work.  I modified FilterConfig.cs to only redirect to the login page if the filter action name was not Login.  This seems to prevent the login page from redirecting back to itself.  I'll keep your blog handy and hopefully will get the change to review it more to improve upon this, but right now I just needed to get this working.

Comment: Here is the code I used:public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

            // check if session is supported
            if (ctx.Session != null && (filterContext.ActionDescriptor).ActionName != "Login")
            {
                // check if a new session id was generated
                if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
                {...

Comment: glad my blog post helped out in some way @boilers222 ..:)